# Wolfram modules returning functions

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, scoping

I am trying to get a `With` / `Module` pair to return a set of functions.

```
Funky[n_] := With[{x = n},
  Module[{LocalFunc1, LocalFunc2, MkLocalFunc},
   LocalFunc1[y_] := x + y; 
   LocalFunc2[y_] := x - y;
   MkLocalFunc[_fnToUse] := With[{UseLocalFunc = fnToUse},
     Module[{LocalFunc},
      LocalFunc[w_] = UseLocalFunc[w] + 10;
      LocalFunc
      ]
     ];
   {MkLocalFunc[LocalFunc1], MkLocalFunc[LocalFunc2]}
   ]
  ]
(Funky[1] // First)[1]
```

Here I expected the output to be `12` but it returns `MkLocalFunc$636015[LocalFunc1$636015][1]` Why won't it evaluate `MkLocalFunc$636015`?

Comment: What is the intent of this function?

Comment: @J.M.'sennui. My guess is that it is for self-education.

Comment: The `MkLocalFunc[_fnToUse]` part is a little odd; this basically restricts `MkLocalFunc[]` to only evaluate on anything with an `fnToUse` head. I wonder if `MkLocalFunc[fnToUse_]` was intended instead, considering the `With[]` that follows...

Answer (score 5):

Simplifying a bit and fixing a typo:

```
Funky[n_] := Module[{LocalFunc1, LocalFunc2, MkLocalFunc},
  LocalFunc1[y_] = n + y;
  LocalFunc2[y_] = n - y;
  MkLocalFunc[fnToUse_] := Module[{LocalFunc},
    LocalFunc[w_] = fnToUse[w] + 10;
    LocalFunc];
  {MkLocalFunc[LocalFunc1], MkLocalFunc[LocalFunc2]}]

(Funky[1] // First)[1]
(*    12    *)
```

The only typo that mattered was the one @J.M. pointed out: replace `_fnToUse` by `fnToUse_`.

Note that the `With` clauses are superfluous and clutter the code.

Answer (score 5):

In Mathematic this sort thing is much more easily done with [`Function`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) Like so:

```
Funky[n_] := {(n + # + 10) &, (n - # + 10) &}
{f, g} = Funky[1]
```

> {1 + #1 + 10 &, 1 - #1 + 10 &}

Then

```
f[1]
```

> ```
> 12
> ```

```
g[1]
```

> ```
> 10
> ```

Now let's look at what `(1 + # + 10) &` means.

```
(n + # + 10) & // FullForm
```

> ```
> Function[Plus[1, Slot[1], 10]]
> ```

where `Slot[1]` is a descriptor for the 1st argument and we see that `Function` is indeed what the Mathematica evaluator sees.

Sometimes it is useful or even needful to skip the keyboard shortcuts `&` and `#`, and in such cases one can and should dispense with `Slot` and use symbols to indicate its argument(s). An example is a function that takes an integer as its argument and returns a function accepting a list and returning all elements in the list that are to right of the specified integer index.

```
h = Function[i, Part[#, i + 1 ;;] &];
h[3][Range[6]]
```

> ```
> {4, 5, 6}
> ```